# Impose conditional IF statement while updating dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on determining the maximum value (third value in the tuple) shared between the first two values presented in the tuple.

I created a defaultdict that utilizes the sorted concatenated values of the first two values of the tuple as the dic key and assign the dic value as the third value of the tuple.

How can I impose a condition so that when I come across the same pairing I replace the dic value with the larger value? I only want to read through my list once to be efficient.

```
users = [
    ('2','1',0.7),
    ('1','2', 0.5),
    ('3','2', 0.99),
    ('1','3', 0.78),
    ('2','1', 0.5),
    ('2','3', 0.99),
    ('3','1', 0.78),
    ('3','2', 0.96)]

#The above list is much longer ~10mill+, thus the need to only read through it once. 
#Current code

from collections import defaultdict

user_pairings = defaultdict()

for us1, us2, maxval in users:
    user_pairings[''.join(sorted(us1+us2))] = maxval ##-> How to impose the condition here? 

print(user_pairings)
```

**EDIT**
Just realized a major flaw in my approach. If the values used for keys are not single digit, then my output will not be the correct result due to using 
`sorted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dictionary `get` method to check if a `key` already exists in the dictionary, returning `0` if it doesn't, and then assign the `max` of that value and the current value to the `key`:

```
user_pairings = {}

for us1, us2, maxval in users:
    key = '-'.join(sorted([us1, us2]))
    user_pairings[key] = max(maxval, user_pairings.get(key, 0))

print(user_pairings)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
{'1-3': 0.78, '2-3': 0.99, '1-2': 0.7}
```

Note I don't see much point in converting `us1` and `us2` into a string so that `sorted` can then split it back out into a list. May as well just use a list `[us1, us2]` to begin with.

By using a list and `join`ing with a character (I've used `-` but any would do), we can avoid the issue that can arise when the `us1` and `us2` values have multiple digits (e.g. if `us1, us2 = 1, 23` and `us1, us2 = 12, 3`).

Comment: @MBakir please see my edit, it addresses the issue you have raised in your edit.

Answer (score 0):

On way of doing it would be to replace:

```
    user_pairings[''.join(sorted(us1+us2))] = maxval
```

With:

```
    key = ''.join(sorted(us1 + us2))
    user_pairings[key] = max(maxval, user_pairings[key] if key in user_pairings else 0)
```

Comment: Note that `key` is only there to save having the same expression twice